# How to reschedule 403 HTTP status codes to be crawled later in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

As per [these](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry) instructions I can see that HTTP 500 errors, connection lost errors etc. are always rescheduled but I couldn't find anywhere if 403 error are rescheduled too or if they are simply treated as a valid response or ignored after reaching the retry limits.

Also from the same instruction:

> Failed pages are collected on the scraping process and rescheduled at
>   the end, once the spider has finished crawling all regular (non
>   failed) pages. Once there are no more failed pages to retry, this
>   middleware sends a signal (retry_complete), so other extensions could
>   connect to that signal.

What does these `Failed Pages` refer to ? Do they include 403 errors ?

Also, I can see this exception being raised when scrapy encounters a HTTP 400 status:

```
2015-12-07 12:33:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <400 http://example.com/q?x=12>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

From this exception I think it's clear that HTTP 400 responses are ignored and not rescheduled.

I'm not sure if 403 HTTP status is ignored or rescheduled to be crawled at the end.
So I tried rescheduling all the responses that have HTTP status 403 according to [these](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response) docs. Here's what I have tried so far:

In a middlewares.py file:

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if response.status == 403:
        return request
    else:
        return response
```

In the settings.py:

```
RETRY_TIMES = 5
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]
```

My questions are:

1. What does these `Failed Pages` refer to ? Do they include 403 errors ?
2. Do I need to write `process_response` to reschedule 403 error pages or are they automatically rescheduled by scrapy ?
3. What type of exceptions and (HTTP codes) are rescheduled by scrapy ?
4. If I reschedule a 404 error page, will I be entering an infinite loop or is there a timeout after which the rescheduling will not be done further ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You can find the default statuses to retry [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py#L240).
2. Adding 403 to `RETRY_HTTP_CODES` in the `settings.py` file should handle that request and retry.
3. The ones inside the `RETRY_HTTP_CODES`, we already checked the default ones.
4. The `RETRY_TIMES` handles how many times to try an error page, by default it is set to `2`, and you can override it on the `settings.py` file.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. I pretty much know about retry. My main question is about rescheduling. Are the codes that are retried are also rescheduled ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but retrying is launching the `Request` again.

Comment: `Failed pages are collected on the scraping process and rescheduled at the end, once the spider has finished crawling all regular (non failed) pages.`  I'm talking about this rescheduling.

Comment: retrying and rescheduling are the same here, it doesn't really wait for ALL requests to finish, when retrying scrapy lowers the priority of that new request, so requests with higher priority will be executed before as possible.

Comment: Cool. So what happens when the retry limit is over ? Does it discard the request by raising an exception or it keeps on retrying until it gets a valid response ?

Comment: It goes to the errback method specified on the Request object

Comment: Yup. Thanks for your time. Had to use `process_response` for retrying.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a middleware to your Spider ([source](https://github.com/ArturGaspar/scrapy-delayed-requests/commit/ec661d5e699ed37877d9afbf825077054e8c722a), [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835571/1544154)):

```py
# File: middlewares.py

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

DEFAULT_DELAY = 5

class DelayedRequestsMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        delay_s = request.meta.get('delay_request_by', None)
        if not delay_s and response.status != 403:
            return
        delay_s = delay_s or DEFAULT_DELAY

        deferred = Deferred()
        reactor.callLater(delay_s, deferred.callback, None)
        return deferred
```

In the example you could invoke the delay with meta key:

```py
# This request will have itself delayed by 5 seconds
yield scrapy.Request(url='http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/', 
                     meta={'delay_request_by': 5})
```