# scrapy spider error: 403 HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware, http-status-code-403

I tried to run a spider and getting 403 error. I am pasting the code and output. I found a question similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128490/how-to-reschedule-403-http-status-codes-to-be-crawled-later-in-scrapy). Since I am pretty new to scrapy, I didnt understand much and dont know how to fix my code.

**the spider code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from laptop_sample.items import LaptopSampleItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "laptop"
    allowed_domains = ["specout.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://laptops.specout.com/l/1149/4752-32352G50Mn"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        item = LaptopSampleItem()
        item["title"] = hxs.select("//h1[@class='stnd-page-title']/span[@class='fn']/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

**This is the output I got:**

```
2016-10-21 00:22:58 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: laptop_sample)
2016-10-21 00:22:58 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-10-21 00:22:58 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'la
ptop_sample.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['laptop_sample.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': '
laptop_sample'}
2016-10-21 00:22:59 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsol
e, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, Met
aRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddle
ware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET http://laptops.specout.co
m/l/1149/4752-32352G50Mn> (referer: None)
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <403 http://laptops.specou
t.com/l/1149/4752-32352G50Mn>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 192,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1051,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 20, 18, 53, 0, 750000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 20, 18, 53, 0, 35000)}
2016-10-21 00:23:00 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I have added following line to the setup.py. But, it didnt fix the issue.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,}
```

Any insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP error code `403` is raised when there is a forbidden request. Scrapy automatically adds the `USER_AGENT` as [Scrapy/VERSION (+http://scrapy.org)](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent) to each of the request sent. Though this is not advisable a workaround is to set the `USER_AGENT` to mimic a browser something like `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0` which identifies you as a browser. You can learn how to setup the scrapy spider settings [here](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/settings.html).

Though, it looks like for your question, it could be achived using [selenium](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7nr6K1PjPAhUEMz4KHbSxBWsQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fselenium-python.readthedocs.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEKW5YbePdtoyreYl86QsDyZhhZAA&bvm=bv.136593572,d.cWw). You can create a web driver instance to fetch the data and create scrapy item objects after parsing each response from selenium.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from laptop_sample.items import LaptopSampleItem
from selenium import webdriver

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "laptop"
    allowed_domains = ["specout.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://laptops.specout.com/l/1149/4752-32352G50Mn"]

    def __init__(self):

        # you can initialize any other instance of webdriver if you like
        self.url = "http://laptops.specout.com/l/1149/4752-32352G50Mn"
        self.webdriver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, forbidden_resp):
        browser_resp = self.webdriver.get(self.url)

        # get the page source
        resp = browser_resp.page_source

        # init text response object
        response = TextResponse(url=self.url, body=resp, encoding='utf-8')

        # HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated in version 1.1.0 maybe you should think
        # about using the newer version of scrapy.Selector class instead
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        item = LaptopSampleItem()
        item["title"] = hxs.select("//h1[@class='stnd-page-title']/span[@class='fn']/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: @neenkart are you still trying to find an answer? If you already have found one then please update it here else I will post one in a bit.

Comment: @neenkart I have updated the answer to find a fix using selenium to fetch the response instead.

Comment: @neenkart answer has been updated with the code fix now. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I just logged in here, will check the code and reply you.

Comment: Is there anything I should install along with selenium? I run the code after installing selenium and got following error:
`Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <boun
d method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object a
t 0x046289B0>> ignored`

Comment: Install the latest [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and the the `selenium` pip package

Comment: @ kiran.koduru ok, i will do that and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126847/discussion-between-neenkart-and-kiran-koduru).

Answer (score -1):

What's most likely the problem is that the bot is being rejected. There are various modules to get around this. If you don't understand the spider code, you should perhaps look into the [scrapy Documentation](https://scrapy.org/doc/)

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403